# Server host for python raw sockets use

Tags: python, sockets, udp, ip, openshift

I had built a python udp hole puncher using raw socket and I wonder whether is there a service, or an option to use an external server, on the web(like dedicated server) that will host and run this program.

openshift was something i considered but it  did not work because it uses apache is a proxy and therefore its impossible to use raw sockets for connection.

I prefer a free solution

thanks a lot

Comment: If you are looking for a host of your program this is not the place to ask - I am sure you can find a host yourself - you can get a VPS e.g digitalocean.com. However if you indeed using raw sockets you will not be able to communicate with a host on the Internet - but it looks like you are using IP sockets since you say you are using UDP.

Comment: i am using ip sockets i meant the raw sockets library in python sorry if i confused.

i thought about using VPS but i prefer a free solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a security flaw if a host let this in a webhost product, but you can try any below:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/FreeHosts

You also can use a vps, but is a paid service.

Try linode.

Comment: thanks you vps might be the solution and i really liked the linked you sent!

Answer (score 0):

That will not work on OpenShift, we only offer two kinds of external ports for use, http/https and ws/wss

Comment: i know but im asking for an alternative to openshift